# firebase sending messages to multiple devices on web

Tags: web, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to use firebase cloud messaging application in web application development. I am able to send the push notification to a single client from the server. But I dont know how to subscribe tokens, i.e, sending push notifications to multiple clients from a single server. Is there any example code available for sending messages/notifications to multiple clients?

Comment: The first sample of Cloud Functions for Firebase shows how to send notifications to multiple devices: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I tried that

Comment: If you're having trouble making it work, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without such an MCVE, it seems unlikely we'll be able to help better than the documentation and samples.